# Simple slopes analysis when moderator is in multiple variables

Tags: structural-equation-modeling

I am trying to help a colleague who is testing moderation in a SEM context. Her interaction effect is significant, so she's attempting to conduct a simple slopes follow-up analysis.

The model asks the following question: does child temperament moderate the effects of parenting style on internalizing/externalizing problems? Three parenting styles are being evaluated simultaneously: authoritarian, authoritative, and permissive. Each is a continuous variable.

Thus, the model is simultaneously counting two equations:

Y_Int = b1Authoritarian + b2Authoritative + b3Permissive + b4(Temperament) + b5(Authoritarian x Temperament) + b6(Authoritative x Temperament) + b7(Permissive x Temperament).

Y_Ext = b1Authoritarian + b2Authoritative + b3Permissive + b4(Temperament) + b5(Authoritarian x Temperament) + b6(Authoritative x Temperament) + b7(Permissive x Temperament).

The Authoritarian x Temperament interaction is significant.

Thus, I am advising her to test Temperament at +1/-1 SD, and substitute Temppl1sd and tempmi1sd where needed.

Now here's where things get tricky. I've never done simple slopes in the context of a SEM path analysis. Here's what I'm suggesting, though:

My coworker needs to substitute ALL instances of Temperament for all interactions (not just the significant one). Else, the sample size may change (unless she is using listwise deletion, which would have its own consequences), which would result in fluctuations in the estimated parameters and render the simple slopes model incomparable to the main model, correct?

All variables are mean-centered.

Answer (score 1):

Compared with interaction models in multiple regression, there is really no substantive difference when probing simple slopes in a measured variable path analysis within an SEM framework.

First off, let me state that I don't think there is only one way to tackle this question. For instance, you could choose to drop the non-significant terms in your model prior to probing your slopes. Or, alternatively, perhaps you want to keep those interaction terms in the model for theoretical reasons. Maybe there is something relevant to being able to make a statement about the interaction between authoritarian parenting and temperament, controlling for interactions between other parenting style dimensions and temperament.

Whether you drop or keep the other terms in the model, there are really only three coefficients you should focus on in my mind: $\hat{\beta_0}$ (note that as it looks like you have centered your variables and have not included intercepts in the model this should equal 0), $\hat{\beta_4}$, and $\hat{\beta_5}$. Alternatively, if you cared about making a statement about the change in relation between authoritarian parenting and your outcome variable as a function of child temperament you would swap $\hat{\beta_1}$ with $\hat{\beta_4}$.

From here you can apply existing formulas for the calculation of simple slopes involving two-way interactions. I tend to generally dislike the selection of static values when probing simple slopes, but that is sort of my pet peeve. My colleagues and I have taken a slightly different approach that probes simple slopes along a range of continuous plausible values ([Barstead et al., 2017](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/jora.12350/full); [Smith et al., 2017](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10964-016-0594-z)). The main reason I dislike the selection of static values for simple slope analyses is what happens when your simple slope is not significant at 1 SD above the mean, but it is at 1.1 SD above the mean? I just don't know how much meaning to place on the transition across the $p<.05$ threshold associated with a change of .1 SD.

In any case, a good site that provides the necessary formulas for calculating your simple slopes is [Kristopher Preacher's site](http://www.quantpsy.org/interact/interactions.htm). If you take the approach I am advocating and you keep in your *ns* interaction terms and other parenting covariates, you will essentially be making a statement about estimated simple slopes at different levels of your moderator controlling for other dimensions of parenting.

Good luck.

References: 
Barstead, M. G., Smith, K. A., Laursen, B., Booth-LaForce, C., King, S., & Rubin, K. H. (2017). Associations between motivations for social withdrawal and internalizing problems during the transition to high school: The role of positive parent and best friend relationships. *Journal of Research on Adolescence*. doi: 10.1111/jora.12350

Smith, K. A., Barstead, M. G., & Rubin, K. H. (2017). Neuroticism and conscientiousness as moderators of the relation between social withdrawal and internalizing problems in adolescence. *Journal of Youth and Adolescence, 46*, 772-786. doi: 10.1007/s10964-016-0594-z